# Is it possible in SQL to match a LIKE from a list of records in a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

Using these tables, as a sample:

**CodeVariations**:

```
CODE
-----------
ABC_012
DEF_024
JKLX048
```

**RegisteredCodes**:

```
CODE       AMOUNT
--------   ------
ABCM012         5
ABCK012        25
JKLM048        16
```

Is it possible to write a query to retrieve all rows in *RegisteredCodes* when CODE matches a pattern in **any** row of the *CodeVariations* table? That is, any row that matches a LIKE pattern of either `'ABC_012'`, `'DEF_024'` or `'JKLX048'`

Result should be:

```
CODE       AMOUNT
--------   ------
ABCM012         5
ABCK012        25
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, but it would be interesting to know if it's possible to do this in a simple query for either PostgreSQL or any other DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
select distinct RC.* from RegisteredCodes RC, CodeVariations CV
where RC.CODE LIKE CV.CODE;
```

Comment: It needs to be a SELECT DISTINCT if you want to allow the situation where a CODE could be LIKE more than one of the CODEVARIATIONS.CODE

That doesn't happen in the data as given, but there are possible code variations where it could.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for:

```
SELCET * FROM RegisteredCodes RC WHERE RC.Code IN (SELECT CODE FROM CodeVariations WHERE CODE LIKE ('ABC%') AND CODE LIKE ('%012')
```

This will fetch all the record that start with 'ABC' and Ends with '012' and similar for 'DEF" and 'JKL'.

OR

Are you looking for something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle & PostgreSQL you can you single char wildcards "_" for single chars.

```
select RC.* from RegisteredCodes RC, CodeVariations CV
where RC.CODE LIKE 'ABC_012';
```

use Substring

```
select RC.* from RegisteredCodes RC, CodeVariations CV
where RC.CODE LIKE substring(CV.Code,1,3)||'_'||substring(CV.Code,5) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from CAT_ITEM where DESCRICAO LIKE '%TUBO%%PVC%%DNR%'
```

All like list is in a string.